# Can one person show me a way to do this in Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm going nuts. I've posted multiple questions that all stem from THIS.
I have a HtmlService that is displaying a modalDialog.

From here, the user picks something from a drop down menu.
The JS code then submits the data server-side to a function where it can be logged.

Great! But I need to be able to call that function from ANOTHER FUNCTION with that data that was chosen from the dropdown.

I've had (amazing) people help me out and guide me on different parts of this, but in the end, I have gotten no response that works.

html file:

```
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">

</head>
<body>
  <form>
   <select id="dropJob" name="dropdown">
     <option value=""></option>
   </select>
   <br>
     <br>  
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="action" onclick="sendData()" />       
   <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
</form> 

<script>
  $(function() {
  $('#dropJob').val('');
  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(updateSelect)
    .getSelectOptions();
  });

  function updateSelect(vA) {//this is where the dropdown gets loaded
    var select = document.getElementById("dropJob");
    select.options.length = 0; 
    for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++)
    {
      select.options[i] = new Option(vA[i],vA[i]);
    }
  }

  function sendData(){
    var value = document.getElementById("dropJob").value;
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(closeIt).grabData(value);
  };
  function closeIt(){
    google.script.host.close()
  };

  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

.GS file:

```
function reserveItem() { 
  var response = ui.prompt("Add to Reservation","Please enter project 
  name",Browser.Buttons.YES_NO_CANCEL);       

  if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.YES) {
    var projectname = response.getResponseText();

    //Bunch of stuff-not important

  }
  else if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.NO){
    displayDropdown();
    var projectname = PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperty('DropJob')
    Logger.log(projectname);  
**//This is where I need that value from the dropdown**
    //build more sheets//update cells//not important
    }
}
```

And finally the function that the client-side code sends the data too from the dropdown:

```
function grabData(value) {
  return value;
}
```

Comment: Please show all of the pertinent html, like the `select` so I can get a total picture of what your doing.

Comment: @Cooper updated html file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example that's pretty close to your code and it works.  I started with your html and modified a few places.

Code.gs:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My Tools')
  .addItem('Start Dialog', 'startDialog')
  .addItem('grabData','grabData')
  .addToUi();
}

function startDialog() {
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('zzzz');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'zzzz');
}
```

I'm getting my select options from Sheet1 Column1

```
function getSelectOptions() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow());
  var vA=rg.getValues().map(function(r){return r[0];});
  return vA;
}

function saveData(v) {
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('DropJob', v);
  Logger.log(v);
  return v;
}
```

I logged the v leaving client side and returning just to make sure I was getting it. And grabData() just displays the contents of the Script Properties and User Properties works also.

```
function grabData() {
  var data=PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('DropJob');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Current Data is ' + data);
}
```

HTML:zzzz.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">

</head>
<body>
  <form>
   <select id="dropJob" name="dropdown">
     <option value=""></option>
   </select>
   <br>
     <br>  
   <input type="button" value="Submit" class="action" onClick="sendData();" />
```

I changed the above button type.

```
   <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close();" />
</form> 

<script>
  var gv='';
  $(function() {
  $('#dropJob').val('');
  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(updateSelect)
    .getSelectOptions();
  });

  function updateSelect(vA) {//this is where the dropdown gets loaded
    var select = document.getElementById("dropJob");
    select.options.length = 0; 
    for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++)
    {
      select.options[i] = new Option(vA[i],vA[i]);
    }
  }

  function sendData(){
    var value = document.getElementById("dropJob").value;
    console.log('value: %s',value);
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(function(v){
       console.log('value: %s',v);
       gv=v;//if you want to pass the last selected value back to Javascript
       google.script.host.close();
    })
    .saveData(value);
  }
```

I used an anonymous function in the SuccessHandler above.

```
  console.log('My Code');
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

There are some changes so look it over carefully.

Comment: I edited my .gs file to reflect the changes. What I need to happen is if the user clicks "no" on the prompt dialog, the modaldialog is called. And this is where that all comes into play. So as I have it, is that correct? Can I set a variable to equal PropertiesService?

Comment: You can store a variables value in the Properties Service.  This is a server side service.

Comment: I'm so confused. If I can't get the value from the return of saveData() to use in another function...